# Generic Method to delete sub entities in C#/Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity

I cannot figure out how to create a generic method that will allow me to delete sub entities from an entity.

**Example:**

```
context.Set<ARC_Records>().Local[0].ARC_Addendum.Remove(object);
```

I want `ARC_Records` and `ARC_Addendum` to be generics, so this method can be used in all cases. Any ideas, I am sure this has been done, I am just not that familiar with generics in C#.

Comment: Would creating your foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE` be the solution for you?

Comment: No, I need to keep the original entity and only delete one specific sub entity

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. How are ARC_Addendum and ARC_Records related? Does ARC_Addendum have an explicit remove(object) method, is it inheriting it from a base class?

Comment: ARC_Records and ARC_Addendums are entity framework objects so I think they inherit from DBset.  There is a 1 to many relationship between ARC_Records and ARC_Addendums.                                                public DbSet<ARC_Addendum> ARC_Addendum { get; set; } public DbSet<ARC_Addendum> Records { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can create generic method from any ordinary method. You just should put appropriate constraints (which often makes generics usage senseless). In this particular case you need generic way to select ARC_Addendum collection from local ARC_Records entity. This can be done via Func delegate

```
public static void WeirdMehod<TOne, TMany>(this DbContext context, 
    Func<TOne, ICollection<TMany>> collectionSelector, TMany item)
    where TOne : class
{
    collectionSelector(context.Set<TOne>().Local[0]).Remove(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
context.WeirdMethod<ARC_Record, ARC_Addendum>(r => r.ARC_Addendum, obj);
```

If you will make this as extension to DbSet then types can be inferred from usage:

```
db.Set<ARC_Record>().WeirdMehod(r => r.ARC_Addendum, obj);
```

But I don't see any benefit from generics usage here. This logic doesn't seems as candidate for generalization to me.